# Event propagation with ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I stumbled upon a strange behavior of... I am not sure what exactly is behaving strangely...

I am trying to make my "cloud" and I am now at a point when I am implementing showing a folder structure off the server. On click event browser sends a request to PHP script and receives a folder list of a clicked folder. It works... But folder lists start to multiply every step deeper. While testing when it starts to double I discovered, that $.ajax sends multiple times (multiplied by "depth" index), without request (adding just placeholders instead of actual folder list) works like a charm! AND if I add, just before $.ajax, request a line where I append something to an event.target it works too! Why is that?

I mean.. it works but I do not feel good about that solution.

Code:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.folders', function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    let trgt = event.target;
    if (trgt.className != 'folders') {
       return;
    }
    let parent_id = trgt.id;
    let list_id = trgt.id;
    list_id = list_id.split('_');
    list_id.shift();
    if (trgt.childNodes.length > 1) {
       return
    };
    $(trgt).append(' '); //this line stops a problem... But why??
    $.ajax({
       url: 'folders.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
          'request': 'subfolder',
          'list_id[]': list_id,
       },
       success: function (subreply) {
          subreply = subreply.replace(/\["|\"\]/g, '')
          subreply = subreply.split('","');
          i = 0;
          subreply.forEach(path => {
             $(trgt).append('<ul class="folders" id="' + parent_id + '_' + i + '">' + path + '</ul>');
             console.log(path);
             i++;
          });
       }
    })
 })
```

Comment: `$(trgt).append(' ');` adds a text node which will count as a `childNode`. Don't you want to return if there are any childNodes and not wait until there are at least 2?

Comment: Does it? Doesn't it add a space to the folder name, because event.target is a div with just a folder name in the moment of executing that line? So instead of 'Folder name' it should change to 'Folder name '. I am checking the length of childNode to stop request to send everytime I click on a folder that was already loaded.

Comment: Ok... I assumed it was empty element since no html was provided . Please provide a [mcve] so we can help debug this

Comment: Nevermind... I fixed it by adding "event" into function input parameters. Before the stopPropagation function did not work at all. I still have no idea why it was working with that appending.

Comment: Because `event` is not global in some browsers